# Appending a string before Count Function in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, count

I have 2 issues with below query

1) I want to append 'HDR' before the output of below query

```
select unique count(quote_id)
from    T_CONV
```

I tried various ways

```
select 'HDR'|| unique count(quote_id)
from    T_CONV

select 'HDR' + unique count(quote_id)
from    T_CONV
```

but none of them is working

Please let me know how to do that.

2) I also want to ensure that output of count should immediately start after HDR without any spaces or tabs , for that I tried RPAD function but that is not working with count function.

help is highly appreciated

Comment: Does Oracle have a convert function? Something like CAST(COUNT(quote_id) AS VARCHAR)?

Comment: What is your intension with the `unique` keyword. It does not make sense as it is a synonym for `distinct`. But as your statement will only return a single row, using `distinct` (or `unique`) does not make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
select 'HDR' || count(quote_id)
from    T_CONV
```

Answer (score 3):

try

```
select concat('HDR', count(distinct quote_id)) 
from T_CONV
```

Comment: Might be worth noting that `distinct count(quote_id)` is not the same as `count(distinct quote_id)`; in the first case the distinct (or unique) doesn't do anything.